# facebook error : OAuthException, errorMessage: Error validating access token in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am working on facebook integration on my android application. When i do wall post then facebook give me this error :

```
{Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 190, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: Error validating access token: User 100002309500077 has not authorized application 390611174384274.}, isFromCache:false}
```

Steps of getting this problem :

1. in fresh application facebook works fine. (i did login in facebook and give permission for posting and wall will be posted sucessfully on facebook).

but after it i open my facebook account and delete that facebook app from my account.

now i again click on post wall button of my android app . at this time facebbok not asking me for permission and continue with the code of wall post and gives me error posted above.

Now if i again click on share on facebook button then it gives me a exception

```
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to open an already opened session.
at com.facebook.Session.open(Session.java:947)
at com.facebook.Session.openForRead(Session.java:385)
at com.quytech.androidclient.MainWindow.onClickFacebookRequest(MainWindow.java:2605)
at com.quytech.androidclient.MainWindow.onOptionsItemSelected(MainWindow.java:291)
at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.onMenuItemSelected(SherlockActivity.java:197)
at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackOptionsItemSelected(ActionBarSherlock.java:600)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:533)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:738)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:148)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.onMenuItemClick(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:607)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:154)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:885)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:545)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:122)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9293)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4310)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

code which i am using :

```
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };



    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (   exception instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException ||
                exception instanceof FacebookAuthorizationException) 
        {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainWindow.this)
                    .setTitle("cancel")
                    .setMessage("your permission has expired.")
                    .setPositiveButton("ok", null)
                    .show();

        } 

    }




private void onClickFacebookRequest() 
 {
        if (session.isOpened()) 
        {
            sendRequests();

        } else {
            StatusCallback callback = new StatusCallback() {
                public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                    if (exception != null) {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainWindow.this)
                                .setTitle(R.string.login_failed_dialog_title)
                                .setMessage(exception.getMessage())
                                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok_button, null)
                                .show();
                     session = createSession();
                    }
                }
            };
            pendingRequest = true;


            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(callback));
        }
    }
 private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
 private static final String PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY = "pendingPublishReauthorization";

 private void sendRequests() 
 {

     List<String> permissions = quytechApps.getSession().getPermissions();
        if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
            pendingRequest = true;
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                    .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
            return;
        }

        showValidationDialog("Please Wait.posting Data on Facebook");
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.splash_screen_final4);

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

        Bundle postParams=new Bundle();
        postParams.putByteArray("photo",byteArray);
        postParams.putString("message", "Hi Friends I am using Twinqli Chat App.");

        Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "me/photos", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback()
        {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // showPublishResult(getString(R.string.photo_post), response.getGraphObject(), response.getError());
            if(response.getError() == null)
            {
                Log.d("GraphApiSample.java Sucesses","sucess");
                dismissValidatingDialog();
            }
            else
            {
                dismissValidatingDialog();
                session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
                //quytechApps.getSession().
                //quytechApps.setSession(null);
//                  Log.d("GraphApiSample.java",""+response.getError().getErrorMessage());
            }

            }

        });
        request.executeAsync();
 }

 private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset) {
        for (String string : subset) {
            if (!superset.contains(string)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

 static final String applicationId = "390611174384274";
 boolean pendingRequest;
 static final String PENDING_REQUEST_BUNDLE_KEY = "com.facebook.samples.graphapi:PendingRequest";

 private Session createSession() 
 {
        Session activeSession = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (activeSession == null || activeSession.getState().isClosed()) 
        {
            activeSession = new Session.Builder(this).setApplicationId(applicationId).build();
            Session.setActiveSession(activeSession);
        }
        return activeSession;
    }

 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (qsession.onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data) &&
                pendingRequest &&
                session.getState().isOpened()) {
            sendRequests();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        pendingRequest = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(PENDING_REQUEST_BUNDLE_KEY, pendingRequest);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putBoolean(PENDING_REQUEST_BUNDLE_KEY, pendingRequest);
    }
```

can anyone tell me how to handle this situation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is because the session has the read permissions when it is going for posting on the wall

Comment: i could not understand what you want to say . can u explain what you want to say ?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are requesting the session for read

```
session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(callback));
```

and passing the permission for write thats why the exception is occured.